# Hibernate hql substring function is different behavior in postgres and oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate

I using hibernate and oracle when is execute this hql

my oracle dialect is

```
org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

and postgres dialect is

```
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

select u.name,substring(u.name,0,2) changedname 
from User u
```

--result is

```
name        |  changedname 
------------------------------
azizkhani   |  azi
```

But when i migrate dialect from oracle to postgres 
my result is diff

```
name        |  changedname 
-------------------------------
azizkhani   |  az
```

After google that i found postgres position is not zero base 
i dont know why have this problem .
Is hibernate dialect dose not create for solve this problem ?

Comment: Was a cool question! oracle database very complete and fine database than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Both DBMS, the index 0 is incorrect/invalid in the substr() function.

For both DBMS, the first character is at index 1 not 0.

The difference is that Oracle silently treats 0 as 1 [as documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114)

Postgres however seems to treat the 0 differently (unfortunately I can't find anything for that in the manual).

If you use the correct index in your HQL query this should work correctly in both DBMS.